# Count pattern in curl output for a list of URLs

Tags: bash, curl

How it is possible to count a number of times a pattern occurs in `curl` output for a list of URLs, in `bash`?

For example, if URLs in `url.txt` are:

```
xy.com/test.php 
xy.com/test2.php
xy.com/test3.php
```

and both `test.php` and `test2.php` return:

```
{"error":null,"result":true}
```

and I want to count how many times a response `{"error":null,"result":true}` occurs, when I execute a command, to get this:

```
$ curl -i url.txt ....
...
...
Matched result: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you wish to fetch all URLs from the `url.txt` file (one per line) with `curl` and count the number of times the `{"error":null,"result":true}` string appears.

You can do it like this:

```
$ <url.txt xargs -n1 curl -s -i | grep -F '{"error":null,"result":true}' -c
2
```

We pipe the `url.txt` to `xargs` (assuming URLs are properly quoted, without whitespaces) which calls `curl` with one URL at a time (due to `-n1` option). Progress output from `curl` is silenced with `-s`, and `-c` tells `grep` to output the count instead of matches, while `-F` looks only for fixed string given (not pattern matches).

Answer (score 1):

With command substitution, it would look like this:

`curl -i $(cat url.txt)|grep -c '{"error":null,"result":true}'`

Piping the output to `grep -c` makes it so that grep will return the number times the string you're looking for was matched.

Comment: If the URL list is very long, this will fail. For shorter lists, you can use `curl -s -i $(<url.txt) | ...` to avoid the extra call to `cat`.

Comment: Also, if any of the URLs contains a globbing character (`*`, `?`, etc.), pathname expansion will occur.